# Does all clojure code work within a java proxy?

Tags: java, clojure

I was wondering if there is any clojure code or macros that does not work when embedded within a clojure proxy for java code, eg:

```
(proxy [Some Java Interface] []
  (some Java Method [args]
  ...
  Clojure code
  ...
  )
)
```

Or, can I only embed calls to Java functions within the proxy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any Clojure code should work inside `proxy`.

Behind the scenes, Clojure functions are compiled into Java objects anyways, and calling a Clojure function is technically a Java method call itself.  Macro expansion still works normally with `proxy`.  Reader macros all work normally etc.

```
user> (defmacro foo [] "FOO")
#'user/foo

user> (.toString (proxy [Object] [] 
                   (toString [] 
                     (str (foo) \space (reduce + (range 5))))))
"FOO 10"
```